# Does there exist a valid first-order formula whose Skolemization is satisfiable only with uncomputable functions?

Tags: logic, computability

Let $F$ be a valid first-order formula. Then the Skolemization of $F$, let's denote it by $F_S$, is at least satisfiable. Let's say $F_S$ contains function symbols $f_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$, for some $n\in\omega$. Does there exist a formula $F$ such that $F_S$ is true only when each of $f_i$ is interpreted by some uncomputable function $\mathcal{M}^{f_i}$?

Comment: interesting question. "Uncomputable" meaning not recursive? It can be, say, Turing-equivalent to the Halting Problem?

Comment: Yes, non recursive, and yes.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite/not yet an answer to your question about *valid* formulas, but:

This is true anyway for *satisfiable* formulas, in models of a theory $\mathscr{T}$ such as PA with "enough arithmetic" to talk about syntax, or equivalently, Turing machines. Start with the Kleene T-predicate:

> $T(e,x,y) \iff$ $e$ encodes a Turing machine $M$, $y$ is a terminating computation of $M$ on input $x$.

T is arithmetical (even primitive recursive). A formula representing the Halting Problem, a complete semi-computable (r.e.) set, is:
$$
K(e) \iff \exists y \, T(e,0,y) \text{.}
$$

The following is a theorem:
$$
\vdash \forall e \exists z\,((z = 1 \wedge K(e)) \vee (z = 0 \wedge \neg K(e)) \tag{$S_1$}
$$

In any model of $\mathscr{T}$, any Skolem function $f(e)$ for $z$ will "solve" the Halting Problem and is not computable. It's Turing degree is $\mathbf{0'}$. Similarly, by using $K_n(e)$ instead of $K(e)$ where $K_n(e)$ is a formula representing a $\Sigma^0_n$-complete set, a Skolem function for the analogous sentence will have degree $\mathbf{0^n}$.

The definition of $T$, and thus of $K$, uses only finitely many axioms $\mathscr{T_0}$ of $\mathscr{T}$, so one could form the sentence $\vdash \bigwedge \mathscr{T_0} \to S_1$. Among the models will be nonstandard models of $\mathscr{T}$ — say, nonstandard models of PA; by a result of Tennenbaum, in such models even $+$ and $\times$ are non-computable. However, this sentence will also have models that aren't models of $\mathscr{T}$, because not every instance of the induction schema is in $\mathscr{T_0}$. In those models, it might not even be clear what "computable" means.

Comment: I was thinking of the same idea, but could you pack all the necessary arithmetical stuff (axioms) within the same (finite) formula? By "valid" I was thinking of "valid on all models". If you could pack all the necessary arithmetical formulas into a single formula A, then "A & <your formula>" would be a solution. (sorry if I mislead you in a comment above)

Comment: Good question: you can for theorems of $T$. If $T\vdash S$ then only finitely many axioms $T_0$ of $T$ are used in the proof of $S$, so $\vdash \bigwedge T_0 \to S$ is valid. But I have to think carefully about whether/how this applies to (S).

Comment: Perhaps with Robinson arithmetic instead of PA? By the way, is (S) valid on all the models of PA? I noticed you added "This is true anyway for satisfiable formulas" - did you mean that (S) is only satisfiable (even when restricted to models of PA)?

Comment: I emended my answer, used more standard names for things, and included what had been my previous comment.

Comment: So, the problem now (at least with this line of thought) would be to see if we can add enough formulas (restrictions to class of models) to $\mathscr{T_0}$ in order to make (S) capture the notion of computation (so that the witness function for (S) solves the actual halting problem). Do you agree?

Comment: I do. But for these purposes we're only interested in models where the notion of "computable" makes sense :)

Comment: I think I've answered my own question. If correct, my question was a bit trivial.

Comment: Not trivial, just overly broad; too many models to consider. For computability we're interested in models of arithmetic, standard or not.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer to my question is no, there are no such formulas. The reason is somewhat trivial.

If $F$ is a valid formula, then it's also satisfied on a model $\mathcal{M} = (D, I)$ where $|D| = 1$. There is just one possible variable assignment $v$ on such model: $v(x_i) = d$, where $d$ is the only $d \in D$.
Because of this, both $\forall x \phi(x)$ and $\exists x \phi(x)$ have the same truth value (according to $\mathcal{M}$) as just $\phi(x)$. If we assume w.l.o.g. that $F$ was in prefix normal form, then $F$ with no quantifiers is the same as $F_S$ with no quantifiers, with the exception of $F_S$ having certain Skolem function (sub)terms instead of variables. However, every term regardless of content is interpreted as $d$, and so this syntactic difference makes no difference for evaluation. Since $\mathcal{M}\vDash F$, it follows that $\mathcal{M}\vDash F_S$. All the functions are projection functions, which are computable.

Comment: So perhaps the question to ask is: is there such a sentence $F$ valid only in infinite models and, in particular, in models of arithmetic, such that the  Skolem functions for $F_S$ are uncomputable, in models where we can talk about computability?

Comment: Yes, or perhaps to ask for a sentence F that is satisfiable, not necessarily valid, and whose Skolemization is satisfiable only in models with uncomputable functions. (which is another thing I would change in my original question - I would now ask for (just) one uncomputable function)

Comment: Yeah you can't ask for "every Skolem function" (in *any* model) to be uncomputable. By upward Lowenheim-Skolem, if $F$ has an infinite model then it has models of of all larger infinite cardinalities. In some of those uncountable models, "computability" does make sense (for example, see [$\alpha$-recursion theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_recursion_theory), $\alpha$ any admissible ordinal), and it will be consistent with the axioms of arithmetic *but* it will not be characterized by them. Really you're interested in models of arithmetic.